# Check is checkbox is clicked?

Tags: jquery

Say for example I have the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-box1" name="chk-box1" value="Check 1">Check 1

<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" value="">
```

I can set the value of the textbox when "chk-box1" is clicked by doing:

```
$('#chk-box1').change(function(){
    var chk = $(this);
    $('#textbox1').val("Textbox 1 is checked")('selected', chk.attr('checked'));
})
```

but how could I set the value of the textbox to empty when the box is unchecked? `$('#textbox1').val("")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yPQ55/1/)**

if you want to show message instead of true or false.

```
$('#chk-box1').change(function(){      
    if(this.checked)
         $('#textbox1').val("Textbox 1 is checked");
    else
         $('#textbox1').val("");
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `this.checked` property

```
$('#chk-box1').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
       $('#textbox1').val("Textbox 1 is checked"); //('selected', chk.attr('checked'));
    } else {
       $('#textbox1').val("");
    }
})
```

or Simply,

```
$('#chk-box1').change(function(){
   $('#textbox1').val(this.checked?"Textbox 1 is checked":""); //('selected',     
});
```